# Outlook Folder View: "Advanced View Settings" Don't Seem to be Captured in Custom View

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I have created a custom view in Outlook. This custom view has been applied to all folders by selecting **View>Change View>Apply Current View to All Other Mail Folders**. However, an option that I selected in **View Settings>Other Settings : "Always Use Single Line Layout"** doesn't seem to be carried forward to the other folders. The other folders correctly show my custom view as active, but I have had to individually select "Always use Single Line Layout" for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by:

1. Applying some other view to all folders.
2. Changing the view in my Inbox to my custom view.
3. Selecting the "Always Use Single Line Layout" option for my custom view.
4. From the inbox: applying the custom view to all other folders.
5. Now all other folders have "Always Use Single Line Layout" option selected!

I believe my confusion arose because the "Apply Current View to All Other Mail Folders" option remained grayed out even as I changed the "Always Use Single Line Layout" or other advanced view settings. The system did not notice that the current view was no longer applied to all other folders and didn't offer me the option of doing this.